# Trying to send process to background without UI lockup

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to call a method in which I send to the background making use of `dispatch_async`.

It should be something that is simple, but for some reasons the UI is still blocked until the method returns.

Here is what I have:

```
dispatch_queue_t privateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(privateQueue, ^
{                  
    __block UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        imgView = [controllerB startProcess];
        controllerC.imageView = imgView;
    });
});
```

I still have to wait for `startProcess` returns before UI is free again.

Then I tried to move `imgView = [controllerB startProcess];` outside of `dispatch_get_main_queue()`:

```
dispatch_async(privateQueue, ^
{                  
    __block UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    imgView = [controllerB startProcess];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        controllerC.imageView = imgView;
    });
});
```

In this case, the UI is never updated with `imgView` but UI is not locked up.

I have tried to use a global queue, but the result is the same (UI has to wait):

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
```

I think I am missing something very obvious here. Either that or it has been long day for me.

EDIT:

In `[controllerB startProcess];`

I am making use of:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am not sure if these methods have anything to do with GCD that causes my problem. The image is just .png.

Been thinking hard on this. Am running out of ideas. The only way I can update the UI with the image is to place the method call within `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, which beats the purpose of using GCD because all UI is blocked until the image is ready and method returns.

Any suggestion would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the code in `startProcess`?

Comment: @Wain Within it I am just making `CGBitmapContextCreate` to resize / process the image. There is no GCD calls in this method and no web calls. Am not using any third party library. Thanks.

Comment: wherefore do you create imgView if you than assign value from startProcess after?

Comment: What image? It doesn't make sense to create an image view, then have a method replace that image view (presumably one which contains an image) and then show that image view. Calling `startProcess` should be  before the switch back to the main thread and you need to determine why it returns a bad image view / image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second approach. Modify startProcess to use completion blocks and update your imageView inside the completion block. This ensures that imageView is updated after startProcess is complete.

Comment: Thanks for response. But it seems like the UI would only update it when the above method is called on main queue, which baffles me to the core.

Comment: You can always switch to main queue in the completion block itself.

Comment: That did it!!!! I still wonder why a `dispatch_group_async` wouldn't do the trick but a completion block did. If you know the details, tell me know. `dispatch_group_async` should have worked. Thanks a lot. I know I will have a good sleep tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible, that -in your 2nd example- when you try to set the imageView on the main queue the asynchronous calculation of the imageView in the background has not finished yet, so it can't display the imageView?
In that case a dispatch group might help:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.name.queue”, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    //Do work
    imgView = [controllerB startProcess];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,queue,^{
    //This code runs as soon as the code in the dispatch group is done.
    controllerC.imageView = imgView;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response. +1. I tried this as well. But it seems like the only way it would work is to run it on main queue and I don't know why. I checked the size of the image after, checked it against nil, etc etc, it is there, but the UI just won't update it. I hope it is not that we must call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in main queue. If you have any other ideas or if you could test run it by creating a method in which `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in another class and do exactly what I do and see if it would work for you, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Afaik you can only update the UI on the main thread. So here is another wild guess: inside the group_notify do `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        controllerC.imageView = imgView;
    });`

Comment: I know that we can only update the UI on main queue. I did exactly that by wrapping in notify in main queue. What I meant was calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` on main queue.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, nonetheless. It turned out a completion block solved it, and I still wonder why a `dispatch_group_async` won't work but a completion block could.